# Linux Kernel code in memory check with sha256 sum

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, kernel

Is there a way of finding the loaded kernel code inside the memory? I mean the bootloader loads the kernel and executes it. The kernel extracts itself and start to initialize the hardware and runs init. As I understand the kernel is saved and loaded from the (b)zImage from disk. This unchanged code I want to find inside the memory of the system and check it.

***I have the following enhancement:***

Create a sha256 hash of the loaded kernel code and compare it to a defined value to audit the security of the system. Therefore I load a module which tries to find the kernel code inside the memory and compute the sha256 sum out of that.

I tried to find the kernel code in memory like that:

```
static struct resource *adhoc_next_resource(struct resource *p, bool sibling_only)
{
  if (sibling_only)
    return p->sibling;

  if (p->child)
    return p->child;
  while (!p->sibling && p->parent)
    p = p->parent;
  return p->sibling;
}

static struct resource *get_kernel_code (void) {
    struct resource *kern_code = &iomem_resource;

    while (kern_code && strcmp(kern_code->name ? kern_code->name : "","Kernel code") != 0) {
        kern_code = adhoc_next_resource(kern_code, false);
    }

    return kern_code;
}

int init_module(void)
{
    void *start,*end;
    size_t length;
    SHA256_CTX sha256;
    u32 *hash;
    struct resource *kern_code;

    kern_code = get_kernel_code();
    if ( IS_ERR(kern_code) )
        return -EINVAL;

    start = (void*)phys_to_virt(kern_code->start);
    end = (void*)phys_to_virt(kern_code->end);
    length = kern_code->end -  kern_code->start;

    printk("%s[%s]:%s address: %0*llx-%0*llx \n", MODULE_NAME, __FUNCTION__, kern_code->name ? kern_code->name : "", 4, start, 4, end );

    printk("%s[%s]: length: %lu \n", MODULE_NAME, __FUNCTION__, length);


    printk ( KERN_INFO "%s[%s]: Init sha256\n", MODULE_NAME, __FUNCTION__ );
    sha256_init(&sha256);

    printk ( KERN_INFO "%s[%s]: Give kernel code to sha256\n", MODULE_NAME, __FUNCTION__ );
    sha256_update ( &sha256, start, length );

    hash = kmalloc ( 4 * sizeof(u32), GFP_KERNEL );

    printk ( KERN_INFO "%s[%s]: Finalize sha256\n", MODULE_NAME, __FUNCTION__ );
    sha256_final ( &sha256, (BYTE*)hash );

    printk ( KERN_INFO "%s[%s]: Hash value of kernel code: %x - %x - %x - %x \n", MODULE_NAME, __FUNCTION__, hash[0], hash[1], hash[2], hash[3] );

    kfree(hash);

    return 0;
}
```

But, I get every time a reboot was done a different sha256 sum.

1. Please explain that what happens ? Something in the memory of the kernel code changed. But what can it be ?
2. Is this concept will be worked ? Or is there not every time the same loaded code in the memory.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the loaded kernel code in the memory"? If you _loaded_ the code, it's in the memory.  I mean you _loaded_ the code into the memory, right?

Comment: When the system boots. The bootloader loads somehow the image of the kernel into memory and starts the execution of the code. The kernel runs and extract itself if it is a (b)zImage. The loading of kernel code is untoughed from my code. I want to find the extracted kernel code in the memory of the system (as you can see in my code) and create a sha256 sum out of that to check if it is changed (somebody replaces some code inside the Image of the kernel). I hope this is clear now?

Comment: Ok I understand you. I write it a litte bit confusing. I do not want to load it. I want to find the loaded code inside the memory. I update the text.

Comment: What you are doing in the code above is to find a structure of iomem with name with "Kernel code" on it. You can see that from `/proc/iomem`.  So what do you mean by the "kernel code"?  Are you looking for a text section of the code?  Do you have embedded bare CPU background?

Comment: BTW, the feature of changing kernel address is called **Address-space layout randomization (ASLR)**.  You can read it [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/569635/)

Comment: Thx Yasushi, this ASLR stuff I have alread checked. I thought that if ASLR is moving the start pos of the kernel in memory arround, there is no problem for my approach. Because I am retriving the memory position from the iomem_resource. (If ASLR has changed it I would get the different position). Or is thin wrong?

Comment: My target is: Getting the memory start position and length of the kernel and check its sha256 sum. As I understand this has to be same on every boot and on every machine if they have the exact same kernel running. I thought the "kernel code" inside the resource list is the loaded Kernel Image. Is this right? Additionaly: I understand that the bytes in memory are not the same like on disk because on disk it is a compressed Image, in the memory it would be uncompressed.

Comment: can you double check on that?  boot your image with the kernel parameter `nokaslr`.  If the hash still changes, I have no idea.

Comment: Yasushu, that doesn't work either. But thank you for all your work! I have made some more research about kernel memory and kaslr. I let my code run under qemu/raspberry pi. That means there is no karls enabled because it is ARM and 32bit architecture (although the Rpi 3 has a ARM 64bit Processor it runs on 32bit kernel).

Comment: This might work only for the monolithic kernel part. When kernel boots it will load modules at non-fixed memory locations as well. So, if the system is compromised and someone loads a kernel module with malicious code - you cannot do anything about this. So if you think you can implement a safe security check on your Linux based system just by calculating it's SHA - you're wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have found by myself an answer for this problem:

1. I have made some more research about memory location of the kernel and so on. I found that during runtime the kernel ".text" section (extracted bzImage) is not stored in the iomem_resource list. I have inspected the address range from the "kernel code" resource (see my previous posted code) and found that most of the bits are 0. Only very at the beginning and at the end there is some code. But this is not "kernel code" I didn't find an answer what the hack is this "kernel code" section. Maybe it has to be the ".text" section of the Kernel Image, but not on my system (ARM 32bit & yocto-linux 4.10.17 ).
2. The KASLR feature ([info here](https://lwn.net/Articles/569635/)) posted from Yasushi is not the problem for ARM 32bit arichtecture. I found inside the kernel defines that this feature is not enabled on this type of system. But it is a very interesting feature.
3. To get the kernel address of the ".text" section I use now the kallsysm functionality. This is a big list of all addresses and exported variables. There are two variables who define the start and end. I use the following code:

   ```
       start = (void*)kallsyms_lookup_name("_stext");
       end = (void*)kallsyms_lookup_name("_etext");
   ```

**Note:** Be carefull with virtual memory vs. physical memory location. Kallsysm output is virtual memory location. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

**Finally:** I get the same checksum for each boot for the same kernel code and I can go on finishing my audit module :-).