# Linux kernel code dynamic measure with sha256

Tags: linux, memory, measure

Recently, I want to implemet the function: dynamic measure the kernel code:[_stext, _etext] with sha256, I create a kernel thread to do the measurement, and calc the hash of kernel code every 2 second, I think the hash should not be changed, but during the booting sequence, the hash has been changged, so I am very confused. and I use the following code to calc the hash:

```
void CalcKernelCodeHash(char *KernelHash)
{ 
//struct mm_struct *mm = &init_mm; 
int CodeLength = _etext - _stext; 
unsigned long kernel_start_address = (unsigned long)_stext; 
int i = 0;

if(NULL == KernelHash)
{
    pr_info("KernelHash is Null\n");
    return;
}


mbedtls_sha256((char *)(kernel_start_address), CodeLength, KernelHash, 0);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Aleksey，I want to know why the hash of the [_stext, _etext] is allways changed, and how to solve it, I want  to get the same checksum for each boot for the same kernel code. so I can finish my dynamic measure module

Comment: @David ,hi, I have saw your question is very similar to mine, can you give nme some advice,thanks ,link is :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065537/linux-kernel-code-in-memory-check-with-sha256-sum